# Adding vector icons before textView like a bullet - Android Programming

Tags: java, android, android-icons

With new vector assets available in Latest Android Studio, I want to add an icon before a textView like a icon/bullet.

Using very small imageView before my textView and adding another image seems weird. I tried `android:icon` in vain.

I basically want to use vector icons like font-awesome icons.
I want Java equivalent for: `<i class = "fa fa-star"></i> Title` - in web designing. I have made `ic_star.xml` available as a vector asset in drawable folder, how to include this layout as a prefix to textView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup TextView Compound Drawables. That's what you want.

Comment: Thanks!! `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_star"` and   `android:drawablePadding="10dp"` was exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply LinearLayout with android:orientation="horizontal"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_star" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextAct1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="This "
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```